# gmail Internal parse error: Illegal envelope To: address (invalid domain name): root@[1.2.3.4]

Tags: centos, postfix

Sending e-mails to my own gmail account from a server without a domain name.

When using internal hostname `basinsrv.localdomain`, cannot reply.

Tried these non-default settings in `main.cf`:

```
myorigin = 1.2.3.4
mydestination=$myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost, $myorigin
resolve_numeric_domain = yes
inet_protocols = ipv4
inet_interfaces = all
```

Can now reply from gmail, but postfix won't accept the reply:

```
Sep 30 11:25:55 basinsrv postfix/smtpd[11639]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from mail-la0-f66.google.com[209.85.215.66]: 550 5.1.1 <root@1.2.3.4>: Recipient address rejected: User unknown in local recipient table; from=<blahblah at gmail.com> to=<root@1.2.3.4> proto=ESMTP helo=<mail-la0-f66.google.com>
```

According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address , the ip address should be in brackets: `root@[1.2.3.4]`

Changed:

```
myorigin = [1.2.3.4]
```

But now cannot reply, gmail says:

```
Delivery to the following recipient failed permanently:

     root@[1.2.3.4]

Technical details of permanent failure: 
Internal parse error: Illegal envelope To: address (invalid domain name): root@[1.2.3.4]
```

Comment: the target mail server is configured with a list of domain names that are valid for it.  apparently `[1.2.3.4]` is not in that list.  i would bet that `example.net` is not in that list, either.  maybe `gmail.com` is in that list.

Comment: using literal IP addresses in email addresses in this way is hardly supported, it's trivial nowadays to use a proper domain name for that.

Comment: Thank you. I guess, I'll just add `Reply-To:` header to all messages